# Cannot access to dockerized SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have simple `docker-compose.yml` which contains two services only, `my-api` and `sql-server`.

```
version: '3.0' 
services:
  sql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    hostname: sql-server
    container_name: sql-server
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=MyPassword01*
      - MSSQL_PID=Express    
  my-api:
    ports: 
      - "8080:5000"         
    depends_on: 
      - sql-server
   ... ommited for clarity
```

When I docker-compose up --build the containers are ready (I can verify with docker ps)
`a7a47b89a17a  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…" 12 minutes ago Up 11 minutes 0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp sql-server`

but I cannot access my SQL Server using SSMS.

SSMS login window:

- Server Name: `localhost,1433`
- Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
- Username: `sa`
- Password: `MyPassword01*`

Error:

> Cannot connect to localhost,1433.
>
> Login failed for user 'sa'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

PS: I also tried with

- Server Name: `sql-server,1433`

but still cannot access

Comment: As a general side-note: you should **not** use the `sa`  account in any of your serious work. This account just has way too much permissions and should be used only internally, and even then very sparingly. Create a separate service account for your app and use that to talk to SQL Server

Comment: On yam config you have `MyPassword01*` but after you use `MyPassword01` without asterisk, is this correct ? Which OS Host and Container do you use ?

Comment: @Max great eye, but it's just a typo when I post a question. I'm using Windows 10 as a host and Linux containers

Comment: @user1765862 check once if your 1433 port for your localhost is already used in some host service. Most probably should be your host machine mssql service should be using. it. Try shutting it down and then connecting to your docker

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below code which will display the public ipaddress.
Instead of localhost use this ipaddress

docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" mssqltrek-con1.

I followed the below link to achieve the same.

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-with-a-docker-container-on-windows-server-2016/

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to work: my general understanding is that this IP address only works if you're on a native-Linux host, and you're making the call from the same physical host (or inside the same native-Linux VM).  (Though that writeup does seem to have done this successfully.)  You should be able to access the service through the published port, regardless of the host environment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to debug further. The first thing I guess you can do is to open the bash inside the container and try to connect to your SQL database from the container.

`docker exec -it sql-server "bash"`

Once inside the container bash, then connect with sqlcmd,

`/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "<YourNewStrong@Passw0rd>"`

If you fail to connect inside the container, then I have to assume your SA password is somehow different when you set up the SQL server. But if this is not an issue, that means, you can connect to SQL server inside the container,  then you can be rest assured it is something wrong with SSMS on port 1433 in your computer. Make sure the server name is correct.